# Advantages of Platform signed android applications

Tags: android, platform, su, root

I would like to know about the extra things that my application can do if it is signed with platform keys. Like switching GPS on/off etc.,

Comment: You can do anything as long as you define a permission. The permission gives you access to a specific function of the platform. Although I don't understand what platform keys are.